# How to make an unordered_map only work with predefined keys?

Tags: c++, c++14

How can I create an `unordered_map`, which will work only with the keys I want and throw an error otherwise.

For example, like in python:

```py
my_dict = {
    'a': 0,
    'b': 0
}
my_dict['c']  # Will raise an error
```

But in C++, the equivalent code will initialize a `'c': 0` pair.

What to do? The most obvious solution is to check the key before passing it to the map, but for a huge amount of keys it could get bulky with a lot of `if`s.

Comment: Make the map `const`?

Comment: ... but mutable values (if needed, eg some sort of pointer)

Comment: @NathanOliver That wouldn't allow for `[]` syntax though, right?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 exactly. So I need to make the map const and the values point to something?

Comment: @cigien Oh, dang.  Didn't realize there wasn't a const overload.  Kinda makes sense.  Guess they'll need a wrapper.

Comment: You can make a thin wrapper and implement your own `operator[]` which throws exception on key not found

Comment: fwiw, I'd argue that `operator[]` is not for accessing values in a map, rather it is to add a key value pair if it does not exist and then access the value. Hence, I eerorikas answer is probably the easiest "solution"

Comment: Do you have any particular reason for tagging this with [c++14]? Please don't add language version tags without a good reason.

Comment: @cigien i'm programming in the 14th standard and I that's enough to tag this question so. How would I know if there isn't standard-specific things which would affect the respondents answer?

Comment: If you're constrained to some language version for whatever reason, that's perfectly fine. I was just checking, so thanks for confirming that.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I would argue that `operator[]` should have been left out of the map interface. It is useful in some cases, but those cases would have been served much more nicely with a named method like `get_or_default_insert()`, so people know what they are signing up for.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili If I could change history, I would have chosen `operator[]` to behave like `at`, and have `get_or_insert` overloaded with specified default.

Comment: @eerorika I like the `get_or_insert` you are proposing. It'd be like a more flexible version of what we have with `operator[]` right now. And having the operator throw would have been better than what we have now, although it would still not be consistent with all other STL containers. It's all about trade-offs, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but in c equivalent code will initialize 'c': 0 pair. What to do?

Simply don't use `operator[]`.

You can use the `at` member function instead. It behaves similar to pythons dict:

> Returns: A reference to the mapped_­type corresponding to x in *this
>
> Throws: An exception object of type out_­of_­range if no such element is present.

Alternatively, you can use `find`, which returns an iterator to the element or iterator to end if element doesn't exist instead of throwing an exception.

---

If you don't want to modify the values, then you can make the map const which will prevent using `operator[]`.

---

If you want to to keep the map modifiable, but not allow adding elements, then you need to define a wrapper class that contains the map in a private member, and delegates the allowed operations.

Comment: so ``at`` function will work only for existing values? and if so, are there any more precautions that should be done, like making the map const?

Comment: @Joe forget about idea of making the map `const`

Comment: @Joe If you make the map const, then you cannot modify its values. If you don't want to modify the values, then you can make it const.

Comment: If you don't modify the map, make it a `struct` at that point. Yes, that's not always possible, but consider it nevertheless.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `find` method and not the deference operator to access the unordered map. If an item is not found an `end` iterator is returned.

Comment: Yes, `find()` much better than the nightmare dealing with exceptions is in this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Use the type system. Define an `enum` with the keys you want, and then only use enum values instead of literals.

```cpp
enum MyKeys { A, B };
std::unordered_map<MyKeys, int> my_map;
my_map.insert({A,0});
my_map.insert({B,1});
my_map.insert({C,0}); // compile time error
my_map.insert({'C',23}); // compile time error
my_map[A]; // works
my_map[C]; // compile time error
my_map[2]; // compile time error
```

Comment: At that point, you could create a struct.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili true, maybe OP would be even better served with a struct.